# Footer content does not appear like footer

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to create a footer. I've been following this tutorial for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZzH7qmkMWw. For some reason, my columns of content for the footer stack on top of each other. Do I need to add rows? How can I fix it to where it lays out like a normal footer such as in the tutorial?

```
<br><br><br>
  <footer>
  <div class="container" style="background-color: transparent;color: white;">
      <div class="footer-content">
          <div class="footer-section Quarantine Pal col-md-4">
              <h2>Quarantine Pal</h2>
              <p class="blurb">Create a connection, make a friend.</p>
              <p>23 Main Street</p>
              <p>New York, NY</p>
              <p>(347) 555-1234</p>
              <p>info@quarantinepal.com</p>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-section links col-md-4">
              <h2>Quick Links</h2>
              <p><a href="#">Home</a></p>
              <p><a href="#">About</a></p>
              <p><a href="#">Contact Us</a></p>
              <p><a href="#">Our Founder</a></p>
              <p><a href="#">Our Blog</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-section social media col-md-4">
              <h2>Social Media</h2>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-section contact us col-md-4">
              <h2>Contact Us</h2>
              <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
              <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message...">
              <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-bottom">
          &copy; quarantinepal.com | Designed by Jamie Tyson
      </div>
  </div>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Hello, You are using bootstrap classes but I don't see the bootstrap script anywhere so add it. Maybe you have forgotten to add the bootstrap script to your page.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's grid system requires both the container and row class elements in order to render columns properly. You should add another div element with the class row like so:

```
 <div class="footer-content">
   <div clas="row">
      <div class="footer-section Quarantine Pal col-md-4">
         ...
```

Also check out Bootstrap docs:

> Column classes indicate the number of columns you’d like to use out of the possible 12 per row. So, if you want three equal-width columns across, you can use .col-4.

You should add divs with class row every time you wish to start a new row.

Answer (score 0):

there can be a maximum of 12 columns in a row so you have to calculate and get them right. What you are trying to do is you are adding the class `col-md-4` 4 times so this leads to overflow that's why the columns are stacking on top of each other instead of side by side.

First, add another class row to the footer-content element. Because bootstrap expects this class when you are starting a new row that contains columns.

To resolve this you need to add col-md-3 class instead of col-md-4 this will be 3*4=12 so this will resolve your problem.

See the snippet below hope this resolves your problem. Click on the full page in order to see all columns correctly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <footer>
  <div class="container" >
      <div class="footer-content row">
          <div class="footer-section Quarantine Pal col-md-3">
              <h2>Quarantine Pal</h2>
              <p class="blurb">Create a connection, make a friend.</p>
              <p>23 Main Street</p>
              <p>New York, NY</p>
              <p>(347) 555-1234</p>
              <p>info@quarantinepal.com</p>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-section links col-md-3">
              <h2>Quick Links</h2>
              <p><a href="#">Home</a></p>
              <p><a href="#">About</a></p>
              <p><a href="#">Contact Us</a></p>
              <p><a href="#">Our Founder</a></p>
              <p><a href="#">Our Blog</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-section social media col-md-3">
              <h2>Social Media</h2>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-section contact us col-md-3">
              <h2>Contact Us</h2>
              <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
              <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message...">
              <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-bottom">
          &copy; quarantinepal.com | Designed by Jamie Tyson
      </div>
  </div>
  </footer>
```